# React component not rerendering when props changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here are my 2 React components - Parent and Child

```
class ParentComponent extends Component{

 render(){      
    /* consultations comes from redux store 
    and looks like { consultation_id:123, date:10/12/2013 } */
   return(
    _.map(this.props.consultations,(consultation)=>{

      return{
        <ChildComponent consultation={consultation} />
      }
    })
   );
  }
}

class ChildComponent extends Component{

  render(){
  return(
    <div>this.props.consultation.date</div> 
  );
  }
}
```

My problem is that I have certain actions that modify the consultations object. For eg: the props.consultation.date changes in the parent component, but the child component does not re render to show the latest consultation date.

However, I noticed that if I send each item in the consultations object to the child component like `<ChildComponent date={this.props.consultation.date} />` it rerenders when the date changes!

Any idea why React does not re-render components when props sent as an object change?

I could always do with the work around but wondering if this is a bug or am I missing something?

Comment: Can you, please, show us more code? Specifically the part, where you change the props.consultation.date in the parent component.

Comment: That could get changed from any where in the application. ParentComponent is connected to the redux store through connect and I've mapped state to props. That's where props.consultation comes from.

Comment: The problem was with the line consultation={consultation}. I changed this to <ChildComponent {...consultation} /> and I accessed the props directly like this.props.date. My problem is solved! But I wonder why <ChildComponent consultation = {consultation} wouldn't work. Do you guys think it's something to do with {consultation} being a reference to the original props object? And it should be consultation={...consultation}?

Comment: I believe this is by design. Unless you are using `redux` or `mobx`, you will not be able to track all nested objects change that easily. So here you have to mutate the value of the object, which is the reference, to get it refreshed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is to change `consultation={consultation}` to `consultation={...consultation}.` I am still unsure why, but it works!

Answer (score 3):

You should definetly add the key prop with *consultation_id* to the child element. React can have problems rerendering elements without a key prop!

Comment: I doubt it was a problem with that. I already have a key prop to the parent div with consultation id. I guess react should be able to able to reference the Child Components relative to that.

Comment: This shouldn't be the answer to this question! This question instead is really good.

Answer (score 3):

When you map over an array of items, you need to pass a unique `key` prop to each item. This signals to react which element is which.

```js
...

_.map(this.props.consultations, consultation => {
  return (
    <ChildComponent 
      key={consultation.id} 
      consultation={consultation} 
    />
  )
})
```

Answer (score 1):

The details you specified says that you change the date of same object~consultation in parent component and you parent component is getting the data as props.
Now if you mutating the same consultation object it won't make component re-render.

```
consultation.date = /* some other date */;
```

it'll not re-render the component.

But if you change the reference of the object like:

```
newConsulationData = { ...consultation }
newConsultationData.date = /* some other date */;
```

It'll work fine.

In your scenario you might have trouble as you directly mutating the props array object, and passing the same array so I suggest you change the reference of consultations array:
You'll need to

```
 newConsulations = [ ...consultations ];
 newConsultations[index of consultation].date = /* some other date */;
```

This should solve your problem.
When working with react try not to mutate the objects if you want to re-render the component on the changes .

Comment: I am not mutating the props object any where. I am just displaying it. But I guess you may be right in a way. The link where I send the consultation like consultation={consultation} was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think it may be related to data type.

The first approach is passing an `Object` to child component,

```
<ChildComponent consultation={consultation} />
```

the second approach is passing a `String` to child component.

```
<ChildComponent date={this.props.consultation.date} />
```

When the property `date` of the object `consultation` is changed, the object's index is not changed. I think react is referencing an object by its index. Object returns an index not the exact value. The index is the specific address where object is stored in memory. But a string or boolean or number returns the value directly.

I think react is comparing object by index, and comparing string by the value. In the first approach, index does not update, so re-rendering is not happening.

---

The third approach extracts the object properties with spread symbol.

```
<ChildComponent consultation={...consultation} />
```

I think react is referencing the property itself in this approach, as each property is extracted. It's no longer referencing the object, so re-render works.

---

(I used a few `I think` statement here, as it's just my guess. Still need official documents to support.)